# How to get transaction receipt using transaction hash?

Tags: web3js, transactions, nodejs

I deployed a smart contract and done some transactions. Now I want to see the transaction receipt of the transactions. So I wrote this code:

```
 var Web3 = require('web3');
 var web3 = new Web3(new 
 Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/IHyXTwb......Pu')); 
 var txR 
 =web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x1333fbc20a9ad2bb56264.......d6576c");
 console.log(txR);
```

I am getting

> promise pending

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt), `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt` returns Promise to return Object.  Try passing callback to the function as second argument:

```
web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x1333fbc20a9ad2bb56264.......d6576c", (txR) => {
  console.log(txR);
});
```